# Require powershell command to retrieve a specific list and that particular list properties

Tags: powershell

I need to loop through all site collection in a web app and I have to extract the list name called "Project Center" and list down all the list properties. Help required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
$spWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://myapplication.sharepoint.com/"

function getListProperties ($spweb)
{
    foreach ($spList in $spweb.Lists | Where {$_.Title -eq "Project Center"})
    {
        Write-Host "List found in: $($spweb.Url)"
        $spList.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object Name,Value
    }

    foreach ( $subweb in $spweb.Webs)
    {
        getListProperties $subweb
    }

    $spweb.Dispose()
}


foreach ($spSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
    Write-Host "Looking in $($spSite.Url)..."
    $rootWeb = $spSite.RootWeb
    getListProperties $rootWeb
}
```

Don't forget to replace the **spweb** application URL with your SharePoint URL.

Comment: Am getting the following errrors: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.;;The term 'Get-SPWebApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. ;;;'getListProperties' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. Am unable to solve these errors.(I have replaced the webapp url).

Comment: Make sure you are running this in the sharepoint management shell so that the sharepoint snapin is already loaded.

Comment: Hi, the above code worked for me for retrieving list prperties using powershell. I need one more help for display the list properties by exporting it to .csv(export in excel). suggestions are welcome. thanks